# How to make apply() pass the object in one of the arguments of the function (not the first)?

Tags: arrays, r, apply

I have a some high dimensional arrays and want to apply some functions to them. The problem is I cannot tell apply() (or similar in apply family) that the object to pass the function on is not in the first argument of the function.

Dumb example here:

```
data <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
myarray <- array(data,dim=c(5,5,2,2),dimnames=list(NULL,
paste("col",1:5,sep=""),
paste("matrix",1:2,sep=""),
paste("slice",1:2,sep="")))
```

Now, imagine a function with this structure:

```
function(arg1,arg2,arg3,data,arg4)
```

If I want to make apply pass the function to the object "myarray", I need to specify on which argument ("data") is located. I tried this but with no results:

```
apply(myarray,c(3,4),function,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood your right, you need to specify the non iterating arguments. For example:

```
func <- function(a,b,c){
    return(a*b + c)
}

apply(FUN=func,a=10,b=10,someObject)
```

The non specified argument is the argument that is iterated over with your specified vector.

Note that if you have a 1D structure

```
unlist(lapply(FUN=func,a=10,b=10,someObject))
```

Will likely work better.

Comment: Thanks! I specified every argument except the one i wanted to iterate and worked almost well. The output didn't respect the c(3,4) margins in the apply and instead returned a lower dimension array, but since the data I wanted were there, after an array() formatting everything is in order :)

Comment: I also tried another strategy that worked but is hugely risky: Inspecting the function (F2 key), and creating a clone function putting the desired-to-iterate argument in the first place.

Comment: However, this alternative (the cloning function one) may be useful if you don't want to specify all the other arguments